# JavaScript regex to split numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex pattern to split a string into numbers and letters. I.e. `.1abc2.5efg3mno` should be split into `[".1","abc","2.5","efg","3","mno"]`.

The current regex I tried is:

```
var str = ".1abc2.5efg3mno";
regexStr= str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+|)/g);
```

Output obtained is:

```
["1","abc","2.5","efg","3","mno"]
```

The number `.1` is taken as `1` whereas I need it as `.1`.

Comment: `str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+/g);`

Comment: thnk you.. it worked

Answer (score 31):

If it's a matter of separating letters from non-letters, then the regex can be made quite simple:

```js
var str = ".1abc2.5efg3mno";
var regexStr = str.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);
console.log(regexStr);
```

I.e. match a group of letters or a group of non-letters.

Comment: Hi, @Biffen can you please help me understand the meaning of this regexStr what everything is used for in str.match() is used for

Comment: @Avinashjain [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Qr47L9/1) gives a thorough explanation of each part.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @biffen

Answer (score 4):

```js
var z = ".1abc2.5efg3mno".match(/[\d\.]+|\D+/g);
console.log(z);
```