# Splitting array with more digits

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets assume I have following string:

```
(255+23*452-2)
```

Then I use

```
string.split("")
```

so I get an array. But problem is that I only get array like this:
`[2,5,5,+2,3,*...]` which I dont need. I need to get array like this: `[255, +, 23, *, 452, -, 2, )...etc]`

Thanks for advice

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434491/11487957

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match everything that is either a group of digits, or not digit at all:

```js
const string = "(255+23*452-2)";
const components = string.match(/\d+|\D/g);
// ["(", "255", "+", "23", "*", "452", "-", "2", ")"]
```